# Add user to a Json list #PHP #JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

We are trying to add some new user to a Json file from a frontend form.

We pass the code taken from the form via Js, after that we are trying (Via PHP) to pass the value inserted by the user in a json file.

Extract from HTML

```
  <div class="log">
                    <p>Username Nuovo Utente</p>
                    <input class="nome" id="nuovoUtente" placeholder="inserisci il nome"><br>
                    <p>Password Password Nuovo Utente</p>
                    <input type="password" id="nuovaPsw" class="psw"> <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="lo" id="aggiunto">Aggiungi Nuovo Utente</button>
                </div>
```

---

Extract from the js file

```
 let newNom = document.getElementById('nuovoUtente');
   let newPass = document.getElementById('nuovaPsw');

   aggiunto.onclick=function(){
       $.get("utenti.php", { nome: newNom.value , pw: newPass.value });
   }
```

---

Php file

```
  <?php
    $data[] = $_GET['data'];
    console.log($data[]);
    $inp = file_get_contents('pindex.json');
    $tempArray = json_decode($inp);
    array_push($tempArray, $data);
    $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
    file_put_contents('pindex.json', $jsonData);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the question / issue?

Comment: '$.get("utenti.php", { nome: newNom.value , pw: newPass.value });` for your own and other people's security please *DO NOT* send passwords via GET

Comment: Are those hashtags?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your "pindex.json" JSON file is badly formatted and the json_encode function is returning null.

Since you did not tell me how json is, I did this example.
Called users.json

```
{
  "users" : [
    {"nome" : "GeekSilva", "pw" : "123"}
  ]
}
```

The PHP code would look like this.

```
$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$pw = $_GET['pw'];

$data = ['nome' => $nome, 'pw' => $pw];

$inp = file_get_contents('users.json');

//Passing the second parameter to true will be returned as an array
$tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);

// push to $tempArray
$tempArray['users'][] = $data;


$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('users.json', $jsonData);
```

With the second parameter of the json_decode function we get an array and from there we can add an element with the parameters passed via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

First php does not have `console.log();` Might want to try `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Next for the

```
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
```

this will return a stdObject for some reason. To get an array you need to do

```
$tempArray = json_decode($inp,TRUE);
```

with an array you should just need to do:

```
$tempArray[] = $data;
```